# Error while creating dll from C code for Python code

Tags: python, c, matlab, ctypes

I have some C code which uses **"mex.h"**. I am trying to create shared library (ie create dll file) so that it can be used in Python by using **ctypes** library.

Following is the command that I have tried for creating dll file, but I am getting an error.

Command Used

```
gcc -fPIC -IC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include -IC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib -lC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2020b\bin\win64\libmat.dll -lC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2020b\bin\win64\libmx.dll -shared -o whitsmw_Cd1.dll  whitsmw_Cd1.c
```

Error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2020b\bin\win64\libmat.dll
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2020b\bin\win64\libmx.dll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked the paths are correct. I would be helpful if someone can provide some help.

Comment: Wait, you’re building code that uses the MATLAB MEX-interface for use in Python? How is that going to work? You will never be able to create the mxArray objects outside of MATLAB. What are you trying to accomplish here? There already exist ways to call MATLAB from within Python, or Python from within MATLAB. I hope you’re not trying to recreate that functionality?

Comment: I just want to be able to use this C code(that uses "mex.h") in Python. If there is any other way please let me know.

Comment: The code that uses `mex.h` is, I presume, a MEX-file, a MATLAB function. If so, I would guess you want to do this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html

Comment: Yes the mex.h is MEX-file. which you can find at C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include. 

For using matlab engine, the machine on which the python code would be running should have matlab installed. I am looking for a way where I can run this C code using Python (maybe after some transformation) on machine without Matlab.

Comment: `mex.h` is not a MEX-file. A MEX-file includes `mex.h`. See here for more information: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-file-functions.html

Comment: If you want access to the functionality in that source file without MATLAB, you will have to strip the `mex.h` include and all function calls to the MATLAB API (basically all functions and types that start with `mx` or `mex`. And then you will have to create some way to translate Python variables to a format that this functionality expects.

Comment: What terminal do you launch the command from?

Comment: From Command Prompt